# Getting the least common denominator of two decimals

Tags: algorithm

I am currently working on a text based web game, where in I simulate the battle sequences automatically like [MyBrute](http://mybrute.com/) and [Pockie Ninja](http://ninja.game321.com/)

So this is the situation.

We have 2 Players with different attack speed

*`attack speed`*(determines the number of seconds needed for a player to start attacking)

(**Easy Example**) Lets assume Player 1 has *`6s`* and Player 2 has *`3s`*

This means Player 2 will attack twice before Player 1 does

`(its because if two player tied on a attack turn, the one with the better attack speed goes first)`

`(but if they have the same attack speed, the player who have not attack lately will go)`

Now my problem is in the loop.

**I'd like to determine who's turn it is with the minimum number of loops**

for our **Easy Example** we could just create an infinite loop with a counter that increments 3 values to determine whos turn it's going to be and just check if every iteration if we have a winner and exit the loop. `(this is my algo you can suggest better one)`

The big problem for me is when i have decimal values now for *`attack speed`*

**Realistic Example** (*assume that i only use 1 digit for decimal*)

Player1 attack speed = 5.7

Player2 attack speed = 6.6

at worst we could have is 0.1 as a an LCD and use as subtrahend per loop but **i want to determine the the best subtrahend(LCD) value.**

Hope it makes sense.

***Thank you. I appreciate you sharing your great minds.***

**UPDATE**
    //THIS IS NOT THE ACTUAL CODES BUT THIS IS THE LOGIC

```
decimal Player1Turn = Player1.attackspeed;
decimal Player2Turn = Player2.attackspeed;
decimal LCD = GetLCD(Player1.attackspeed,Player2.attackspeed)  ***//THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO DETERMINE***
while (Player1.HP >0 && Player2.HP >0)
{
    Player1Turn -= LCD;
    Player2Turn -= LCD;
    if (Player1Turn<=0)
    {
        //DO STUFF
        Player1Turn = Player1.attackspeed;
    }
    if (Player2Turn<=0)
    {
        //DO STUFF
        Player2Turn = Player2.attackspeed;
    }
}
```

WE CAN USE A FUNCTION LIKE

```
public decimal GetLCD(decimal num1, decimal num2)
   {
        //returns the lcd  
   }
```

Comment: So what result do you want to get? _I'd like to determine who's turn it is with the minimum number of loops_ - from the question it is not clear how to determine who's turn it is, let alone minimizing the number of loops. What do you mean by "_it is_", do you refer at some specific moment in time?

Comment: for my first example 6 and 3.. we can use 3 as a denominator to determine whos turn its gonna be.. now i need to use the same concept but with decimal values... can you help me determine how to do that?

Comment: Taking the GCD of just the digits after decimal point & use that value `gcd` as `0.gcd` as increment? In this way you might need another digit after decimal pt to more realistic(for calculating accurate increments).

Comment: @Dave hmm that is possible.. can you help me with that.. sorry i'm really having trouble.. can you atleast create a generic algorithm example for me? id really appreciate it thanks!

Comment: _we can use 3 as a denominator to determine whos turn its gonna be_ - who's turn its going to be **when**? And how do you determine it? Let's say, if it all was implemented inside a function `whosTurnItsGonnaBe`, what arguments would this function accept, and what it would return?

Comment: @penartur i already have a function that does that... what i just actually want is how to get the least common denominator of two decimals.. im using it as divisor.. thats how i determine them.. do you need my algo for that?

Comment: Then show us at least a **signature** of this function - that is, which arguments does it accept and what it returns. Currently it is not clear neither what are you doing nor what are you trying to achieve nor how are you trying to do this.

Comment: @penartur i updated the question. hope u find it useful

Comment: @PhilipBadilla Again, i'm not asking about the common divisor function, i'm asking about "_whos turn its gonna be_". And your code seems to be incorrect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8053/discussion-between-philip-badilla-and-penartur)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the (Greatest Common Divisor)GCD of Doubles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392091/how-to-get-the-greatest-common-divisorgcd-of-doubles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code processes the battle sequence without using the lowest common denominator. It will also run about 1 million times faster than all possible attempts with using the lowest common denominator for player attack speeds equal e.g. 1000 and 1000.001 respectively.

```
decimal time = 0;
while (player1.HP > 0 && player2.HP > 0) {
    decimal player1remainingtime = player1.attackspeed - (time % player1.attackspeed);
    decimal player2remainingtime = player2.attackspeed - (time % player2.attackspeed);
    time += Math.Min(player1remainingtime, player2remainingtime);
    if(player1remainingtime < player2remainingtime) {
        //it is player 1 turn; do stuff;
    } else if(player1remainingtime > player2remainingtime) {
        //it is player 2 turn; do stuff;
    } else {
        //both player turns now
        if(player1.attackspeed < player2.attackspeed) {
            //player 1 is faster, its player 1 turn; do stuff
            //now do stuff for player 2
        } else {
            //player 2 is faster, its player 2 turn; do stuff
            //now do stuff for player 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the LCD in order to solve your task. If you think that my solution is wrong, then provide an example of input data and the expected output data my code won't return. E.g. "_for the player1 attackspeed = 12.3 and player2 attackspeed = 4.56 i expect it to make player2 turn on 4.56, then player2.turn on 9.12, ... etc ..., but your code instead of making player X turn on XXX, makes player Y turn on YYY_".

Comment: for player1 4.6sec and player2 5.7 sec.. your algorithm skips 5.7sec and not allowing player2 to attack. in 5.7 seconds player 2 should attack and player1 has a remaining time of 3.6... an also this is not actually my code.. i just created a quick write up... my function to determine the turns is perfectly working for my need... i just need to get the LCD for my subtrahend for the time left before attacking

Comment: Before first iteration: time = 0. On the first iteration: player1remainingtime = 4.6, player2remainingtime = 5.7, time = 4.6, it is player 1 turn. On the second iteration: player1remainingtime = 4.6, player2remainingtime = 1.1, time = 5.7, it is player 2 turn as expected.

Comment: _i just need to get the LCD for my subtrahend for the time left before attacking_ - no, you don't need it. This is the most obvious way for you, but it is the most wrong of them all. Again, try to think for example how your alghorithm using LCD will behave with player1.attackspeed = 1000 and player2.attackspeed = 1000.001.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an object oriented language then you can do this:

Players will be objects of type `Player` and there will be a `Timer` object.
The Timer will use the `Observer` design pattern.

Players will register themselves to the Timer with their response time.
When their time is due then they are notified that they can take action.

Comment: yes i can do that... but i dont want to use a timer since im going to create a web app... i want the loop to finish at the least number of iteration. I have no problem with determining the turns.. my problem is minimizing the number of iterations in my loop. thats why i need the subtrahend to be the LCD of two decimals

Comment: My code contains one iteration per turn. Obviously one iteration per LCD will not help you to _minimize the number of iterations_. @avi-cohen is right in what is about the _proper_, _well-maintanable_ implementation. The timer doesn't need to work in real-time, it is just an abstraction making your code easier to mantain. All the implementation-specific details (like determining which turn is it now) could be encapsulated in the timer. Their answer doesn't cover the details of implementation though, which was the subject of your question.